# get stuck on Phonegap file Transfer

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I try to build an app that download some files from server but I get stuck on file path.

My code is

```
function downloadFile(sura_id){

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    fileTransfer.download(
        'http://server8.example.com/afs/113.mp3',
        '/audio/'+sura_id+'.mp3',
        function(entry) {
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
        }
    );

}
```

I put my path as **/audio/'+sura_id+'.mp3** this I don't know if its correct.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: What version of phonegap are you using?

Comment: @SyntheCypher I use Phonegap 2.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these permission in your `./platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also take a look at this post:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/sorry-for-being-gone-so-long-vacation.html

Comment: Then you need to add the URL to your whitelist in order for it to work.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html